# WHERE clause that finds in 123xxx digits

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I try to search all rows that contain

```
123000 - 123xxx
```

So the last three are unknown but must be filled up.

So I dont want to find for example

```
12300 or 1230000
```

Comment: i don't quite understand - how is the data stored?

Comment: Its an integer field. But good question what if it would be a varchar field?

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from your_table
where some_column between 123000 and 123999
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value is a number, then just use:

```
where value >= 123000 and value < 124000
```

If value is a string:

```
where char_length(value) = 6 and left(value, 3) = '123'
```

Comment: It must be left(value , 3) = '123'  http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-left.html

Answer (score 1):

For Firebird version 2.1 and above

```
select * from table_name
where  
  (BIN_AND(table_name.field_name,123000) = 123000)
```

in stored procedure with parameter

```
select * from table_name
where  
  (BIN_AND(table_name.field_name,:p) = :p)
```

Comment: The downside is that this can't use an index.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I agree

Answer (score 0):

If your sure the field will always be an int, you could use

```
WHERE Field LIKE '123___'
```

Doc for _ can be found here: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

In short, _ is a single wildcard character, so on a field which can only be an int, this should match 123000 to 123999

This could also be useful if you have to find any reference to 123 where the last 3 values could be anything, including characters

Regards,
Jamie

Comment: The question is tagged as `Firebird` while you are linking to `mySql` documentation.